# Authorization - mapping a Azure AD group to a Snowflake role

Tags: azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, single-sign-on, scim

We implemented SSO on Snowflake and with SCIM, we're able to provision users in Snowflake

Now, I want it to work like SQL Server authentication where I can add users to the same AD group and create a single login on SQL Server for this AD group. To revoke login permissions I just remove the user from the AD group. To give a new person access I just add them to it.

I would like also to map a role to a group, so, for instance, if I could link an Azure AD Group to a Snowflake Role [Read-Only User for Database X], as soon as I'm adding a user Y in Azure AD Group, this user Y will have automatically read-only access to Database X

Is it possible ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This same concept is possible in Snowflake as well with SAML SSO (for authorization) and SCIM (to sync users and their corresponding roles to SF). The details for this are here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-configure-idp.html

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/HOW-TO-Setup-SSO-with-Azure-AD-and-the-Snowflake-New-URL-Format-or-Privatelink

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/scim-azure.html

Both these together will ensure that the user created on Azure AD will be possible to login with the AAD credentials and the SCIM will ensure that the relevant role management is on the AAD side which is reflected exactly as-is on the SF side.