# Mapping between Azure AD and Snowflake roles

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have seen a similar [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71922653/authorization-mapping-a-azure-ad-group-to-a-snowflake-role) but it doesn't answer my question.
I have a long Azure AD group names and would like to map them to shorter role names in Snowflake. Is this possible? From my understanding the name of the group will become the name of the role (1 to 1), right?

I would be grateful for any feedback,
Rafal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. The Azure AD group name will become the name of the role within Snowflake.

More details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/snowflake-provisioning-tutorial

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/scim-azure.html#azure-scim-integration-with-snowflake